# Perl Deleting element from array

Tags: regex, perl

I have a 2D array in perl. I want to delete all elements which has the pattern <<< or >>>.
I have written a perl code, it works good till matching pattern, however it cannot delete that element, some error occurs.

```
 foreach my $x(@array)
   { 
     foreach my $y(@$x)
     {
        if($y =~ (m/^(\<+)|(\>+)$/ig))
         {
            delete $y;
         }
     }
   }
```

Can you help me to delete that particular element that matches the pattern. (I want to delete and remove from array, not undef it)

Comment: Did you not get the error `delete argument is not a HASH or ARRAY element`? And if you did, why did you not say this in your question?

Comment: Quote from http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/delete.html -- `WARNING: Calling delete on array values is deprecated and likely to be removed in a future version of Perl.`

Comment: A better question is, can you remove the `<<<` values **before** storing them in the 2D array?

Comment: You don't need `/g` or `/i` on your regex. You also don't need capturing groups. It could be simplified to `m/^<|>$/`.

Comment: Unless what you really want is `/^(?:<+|>+)$/`.

Answer (score 4):

Let's say your array looks like this:

```
1  2  3  4
5  X  6  7
8  9  A  B
```

You want to delete `X`. What do you want to happen? What should your new array look like after the delete?

Do you wan this:

```
1  2  3  4
4  6  7
8  9  A  B
```

Or this?

```
1  2  3  4
5  9  6  7
8     A  B
```

That's the first thing you need to decide. Second, you can't use `delete`. The `delete` command deletes a keyed value from a *hash* and not an *array*. If you have an array like this:

```
my @array = qw(0 1 2 3 4 5 X 7 8 9);
```

And you want to delete the `X` (which is `$array[6]`), you'd use the `splice` command:

```
splice @array, 6, 1;
```

Finally, Perl does not have 2 dimensional arrays, so you can't delete a value from a 2 dimensional array.

What you have is an array of *references* to a second array. Think of it this way:

```
my @row0 = qw(1 2 3 4);
my @row1 = qw(5 X 6 7);
my @row2 = qw(8 9 A B);

my @two_d_array = (\@row0, \@row1, \@row2);
```

Or, I could do this by column:

```
my @col0 = qw(1 5 8);
my @col1 = qw(2 X 6);
my @col2 = qw(2 6 A);
my @col3 = qw(4 7 B);

my @two_d_array = (\@col0, \@col1, \@col2, \@col3);
```

When you talk about.

```
if ( $two_d_array[1][1]` eq "X" ) {
```

What is going on is that Perl is messing with your mind. It is making you think there's a two dimensional array is involved, but it's not really there.

A more accurate way of writing this would be:

```
if ( ${ $two_d_array[1] }[1] eq "X" ) {
```

or, more cleanly:

```
if ( $two_d_array[1]->[1] eq "X" ) {
```

So first, decide what you mean by *deleting* a value. In a two dimensional array, if you actually *delete* that value, you end up ruining the dimensional structure of that array. Maybe you can *replace* the value at that point with an `undef`.

Once you do that, you must understand what you're actually dealing with: An array of *references* to arrays.

```
for my $array_reference ( @two_d_array ) {
    for my $value ( @{ $array_reference } ) {
        if ( $value =~ /^(<+|>+)$/ ) {
            $value = undef;   #See Note #1
        }
    }
}
```

**Note #1**: When you use a for loop, the index of the array is a link to the actual value in the array. Therefore, when you change the index, you're changing the actual value. That's why this will work.

If you really, really want to delete the element using `splice`, you will have to decide if you want your elements moving up to replace the deleted value or moving to the left to replace the deleted value. If you want the values to the moving left, you want an array or references to row arrays.  If you wan the values moving up to fill in the deleted value, you want an array of reference to column arrays.

Remember that computers will do exactly what you tell them to do and not what you want them to do. Make sure you understand exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You are applying `delete` on a scalar value, `$y`, and delete is only meant to be applied to hashes and arrays. You would need to do do

```
for my $x (0 .. $#array) {
    for my $y (0 .. $#{$array[$x]}) {
        if (...) { delete $array[$x][$y]; }
```

The *best* solution, in my opinion, is to remove the value before storing it in the array. I am guessing you read it in from some data source such as a file, and that would be the best place to filter it out. E.g.

```
while (<$fh>) {
    ....
    @values = grep !/^[<>]+/, @values;    # filtering
    push @array, \@values;                # storing
}
```

On that note, you *can* also do it afterwards, of course, with something like:

```
for (@array) {
    @$_ = grep !/^[<>]+/, @$_;
}
```

Comment: Your first code snippet matches my requirement, however it gives undef value. I want to remove the element completely from my array.

Comment: @SomnathPaul I encourage you to read my answer more carefully. The "code snippet" you refer to is not the solution I recommend. But this information can only be relayed to you if you read what I write, and this is already written in my answer.

Comment: @SomnathPaul See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16039235/368630). You can't _delete_ values out of a two dimensional array without affecting the structure of that array.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete elements from arrays, by splice function:
`splice(@array, $index, 1);` 1 in this example is number of elements, you want to delete
`delete` function only sets array value to undef

Comment: But I need to delete the element which is represented currently by $y. How do we achieve that ?

Comment: use `for` function to browse array: `for my $y(0..$#array) {}` $y will be the number of element in array

Answer (score 0):

`delete` does not alter array indices so it is not what you want. If you want to delete elements by value, use something like this:

```
foreach my $x(@array)
   {   
       $x = [ grep { $_ !~ (m/^(\<+)|(\>+)$/ig)} @$x ];
       print join(",", @$x), "\n";
   }
```

or, use splice. But then you will need to iterate the array using indices rather than values.

Also see [Perl-delete](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/delete.html), [Perl-splice](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html).